# Java Reading File and storing them in 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list, file

I have this file content:

> 1,38,51,31,33,80,46
>   2,44,21,63,27,46
>   .....

It's going that way. Total number of rows = 81

I want to access this content as follows:

```
example [0] [0] = 1 
example [0] [1] = 38 
example [1] [0] = 2 
example [1] [2] = 21
```

Could you give me a clue about this (in Java)?

Comment: read line, split on ",", next line.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me :)